# Causal and conditional probability

Tags: probability, bayesian, causality

I was trying to understand causal probabilities better by reading this article http://lesswrong.com/lw/ev3/causal_diagrams_and_causal_models/

I was interested in the last example where we have 3 binaries: E, O, and I.

The author looks at 8 graphs and concludes that O->E and I->E is the most likely.

I get how can I prove that I and O are independent. Mainly because P(OI)=P(O)P(I) holds. But I don't understand how O->E and I->E is 'proven'. For instance this doesn't seem to hold P(E)=P(O)P(E|O).

A wider question, is there some algorithm which assesses causality by exploring independence first and then tries to find the graph/DAG which is most likely.

Answer (score 1):

Of all the graphs, the last DAG `{O,I} -> E` is consistent with the observations that:

- O and I are independent of each other.
- O and I are each associated with E.
- Conditioned on E, O and I are *dependent*.

> For instance this doesn't seem to hold P(E)=P(O)P(E|O).

The equation `P(E)=P(O)P(E|O)` need not hold, because, the right hand side is `P(O)P(E|O) = P(O,E)`, which need not be equal to `P(E)`.

> A wider question, is there some algorithm which assesses causality by exploring independence first and then tries to find the graph/DAG which is most likely.

Yes!

- Inductive Causation (IC) algorithm: http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/BOOK-2K/ch2-5.pdf
- SGS algorithm and PC algorithm: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/12/lectures/ch25.pdf
- A Bayesian approach: http://www.kddresearch.org/Groups/Probabilistic-Reasoning/Papers/heckerman97bayesian.pdf